# Why is "Read more" opening a link list in another link box's "Read more"?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I put in footer of my Wordpress website two link boxes, one next to another, with 20 links each (Box1 and Box2). Each box is disclosing 5 links, and hiding other 15 links with "Read more" button. When this button clicked, 15 links that are hidden should collapse or appear.

The problem is, doesn't matter which "Read more" button I click, either Box1 or Box2, only links in Box1 are appearing/collapsing.

Could you please help me and show me where have I mistaken. Please look up the code below. Thanks!

PS: this is the CSS code I found on internet, and I try to avoid JS codes

```css
.read-more-state {
  display: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  /*transition: .15s ease;*/
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state~.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'More...';
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Less...';
}

.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  /*display: inline-block;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  border-radius: .25em;*/
  color: #666;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-2" />
  <div class="read-more-wrap">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/">Link1</a><br>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/">Link2</a><br>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/">Link3</a><br>
    <p class="read-more-target">
      <a href="https://www.example.com/">Link4</a><br>
      <a href="https://www.example.com/">Link5</a><br>
      <a href="https://www.example.com/">Link6</a><br>
    </p>
  </div>
  <label for="post-2" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you understand how the CSS `checkbox` "trigger" trick works?

Comment: Also, please format and indent your posted HTML correctly. It's a mess right now. And please re-post it as a Executable Snippet instead of a single code-block.

Comment: No I dont really understand. I m not really sure how do i "format and indent" the HTML code.

Comment: Ok I approved your suggestion. Thanks. However that is not a solution to my problem. I still have the same effect.

Comment: You had to click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and press TIDY before saving. We did this for you now

Comment: Thank you very much @mplungjan Do i get any solution to this problen for two boxes?

Comment: You might, now we can read your code ;)

Comment: But actually your example does not show the issue. The example seems to work as expected

Comment: When I put two link boxes, one next to another, with identical code HTML+CSS, only one box opens on both button clicks. that is the problem. I know this single example works autonomously.

Comment: I need actually 4 identical boxes one next to another, and they need to open Links on More button separately not effecting each other